# jQuery Mobile: Retain Data After Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, jquery-mobile

Currently, I've implemented a session and I am trying to restore the data in the form with the data that is supposed to be within the session. This is not working.

Is there some special way of retaining submitted data with jQuery Mobile if an error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm there is probably a couple of ways.

1. If you set data-ajax=false on your pages it will work.
2. You could use jquery's data method. http://api.jquery.com/data/
3. Html5 local or session storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: So... you're telling me that jQuery Mobile doesn't like Session?

Comment: Well since it loads other pages into same dom as first page i'm not sure how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that JQM is looking to see (once it submits) if the url that it's trying to hit is already in DOM. If it is it will load that DOM element.  If not, it requests it again but if you browser had cached that page already, the browser will simply return the cached copy.  If the URL for your GET and POST are the same, this is likely the case.

There are 2 things you can do.

1. put some no-cache headers in your page so that the browser knows not to keep it.

   META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"

   META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"
2. place the `data-ajax="false"` on your form tag.